Postfix/Postfwd load balancing
The organization I work for sends a lot of email through our Postfix 3.5.8 servers. This issue we are trying to solve is that we are exceeding Google's mail thresholds, but just realized that this setup cannot work with a load balancer.
There are several systems that use SMTP clients that only send, like JavaMailer and others other tools that only send and have limited controls.  The clients send to an alias address that goes to a load balancer and is distributed to a number of Postfix servers for sending out.
The plan was to set up Postfwd on our existing Postfix servers and set up two or more servers and send the clients to these servers.  The problem is if a load balancer sends to the existing servers that have Postfix and Postfwd setup how would it know if a rule had been exceeded and an SMTP Error 421 has been received, and mail delivery should be delayed.
Are there any suggestions on how best to set up the new receiving servers so that they don't need to be set up one for one with the existing servers.  The idea that I have had, can Postfix/Postfwd be used as its own load balancer that would send mail to a list of servers sequentially or at random and complies with the SMTP servixistinger errors when received.
Please let me know if there are any questions.

You can configure Postfix to handover to a different MTA on a soft fail, but I would STRONGLY recommend not doing this. You'll just end up bouncing mails around internally between your servers.
Indeed you should not be attempting to respond to 4xx responses in your infrastructure OTHER than trying to distribute the traffic evenly across your available capacity and applying IP warm up (via your load balancer).
Achieving both of these at the same time can be a bit of pain. Using a policy daemon to select the next hop transport seemed like the ideal solution when I looked at this recently, unfortunately, postfix only accepts reject/accept responses from the policy daemon, not routing instructions. I had not encountered postfwd before - this may have that capability.
For warmup: plan your growth curves in advance and schedule a progressive config rollout to your load balancers tweaking the proportion of traffic sent to new nodes. Its ok to tweak the flow rates based on SIGNIFICANT volumes of 4xx messages during warmup, comparing new nodes with existing, but don't go faster than one change per day.
